# SSRS Sharepoint Integrated From address in Report Subscription

Tags: sharepoint-2010, ssrs-2008

I need to change the From: address for report subscriptions on SharePoint (running in integrated mode).  I believe you can do this in Reporting Services Config Mgr, but am wondering if there is a way to do this from SharePoint or Sharepoint Config Mgr.

I'm using SSRS 2008 R2 on Sharepoint 2010.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SSRS 2008 R2, there is nothing in SharePoint 2010 or SharePoint 2010 Central Admin that allows you to change the From address. It's strictly controlled through the SSRS Configuration Manager. Your other option is to edit the rsreportserver.config file directly, but why do that when it's safer to use the Configuration Manager? Or you can write an application. You could theoretically create a Web form that you display in SharePoint that would update the server settings. See Method 3 here: http://www.dbafarm.com/blog/2011/02/03/setupdate-the-from-address-email-ssrs-subscriptions/

Comment: Thanks.  Loved the story on your site, btw!